# Reclassify data using filters

Tags: tableau-desktop

My goal is to include or exclude dimensional data, from a calculation that creates a category on that dimension, in this example, `Customer Name`. I have achieve the inclusion/exclusion using Parameters, but they only accept single values. That means I need to create several parameters to achieve a selection of 10 items or more.

To explain the case in full, I'm using `SuperStore` sample dataset on `Tableau Desktop 2021.1`, I have created the following calculation

#### Top 10 Customers

```
IF 
{fixed [Customer Name]:sum([Sales])}>10000
then
[Customer Name]
ELSE
"Other"
END
```

That renders the following visual

[image]

How can I move `Bart Watters` and `Denny Joy` to `Other`, without filtering the data? The idea is providing the user the ability to classify - instead of hard coding the selection into the calculation.

Comment: Have you tried this, not sure if this is what you need: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-gb/sortgroup_sets_topn.htm

Comment: @Anu Thanks for that, but I have chosen customers because they are inside the `SuperStore` data set, but in reality, I'm not interested in them, just as an example. As I said in my question, I want to exclude and include specific customers having a maximum of two dropdowns with multi-select, instead of having 10 parameters or more.